# tabItem not showing composite

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I am trying to create some content for tabItems. I created methods to create each tab. For example:

```
private static void initSolutionsTab (TabFolder folder){
    TabItem solutions = new TabItem(folder, SWT.NONE);
    solutions.setText("Solutions");

    Composite solutionTop = new Composite(folder, SWT.NONE);

    ScrolledComposite topScroller = new ScrolledComposite(solutionTop, SWT.V_SCROLL);

    //Should later hold many groups
    Composite groupHolder = new Composite(topScroller,SWT.NONE);

    Group solutionsGroup = new Group(groupHolder, SWT.BORDER_DOT);

    Label solutionLabel = new Label(solutionsGroup, SWT.NONE);
    solutionLabel.setText("TEST");

    topScroller.setContent(groupHolder);

    solutions.setControl(solutionTop);

}
```

But it is just showing a blank space in the tab. I am missing (or not understanding) something, I know, but I just don't find the mistake.
Can somebody please give me a hint?

Comment: Try  adding - folder.getParent().layout(); to the end of your method after solutions.setControl( solutionTop )

Comment: You haven't set any [Layout](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Understanding-Layouts/Understanding-Layouts.htm) on the Composites

Comment: Both good ideas, thanks, but not solving the problem.
Added
...
 GridLayout masterGridLayout = new GridLayout();
        masterGridLayout.numColumns = 1;


        Composite solutionTop = new Composite(folder, SWT.NONE);
        solutionTop.setLayout(masterGridLayout);
...
But no changes in the results.

Comment: Also add this : GridData gridData = new GridData( GridData.FILL, GridData.FILL, true, true ); solutionTop.setLayoutData( gridData ) before adding the GridLayout

Comment: Again a good idea, but still nothing in the tab.

Comment: I don't see a reason why the composite won't show up. Did you try resizing the tab manually? Also you can try folder.pack();

Comment: You have to set a Layout on **every** Composite.

Answer (score 0):

try to use setSize() for your TabFolder